# get "via" information from google direction JSON

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have a JSON retrieved from google direction finding method in android. Sometimes there are multiple routes between 2 points in google map. Is there any way to get "via" information (e.g. via Julian Street) from this JSON.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxIEA.png)

By the way, I checked via_waypoint array but it is sometimes empty. Mostly first one. If this is the way where should I get the first one.

I use this API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

Its in summary field in Json file

```
"summary" : "‪Khoshk River Rd‬‏",
"warnings" : [],
"waypoint_order" : []
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use Google,s direction api. for more visit [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=en)